# Submit always defaults to first submit button (multi-form)

Tags: drupal-7, form-api

Following the [Examples Module](https://drupal.org/project/examples) in Drupal 7, I'm creating a multi-step form. Page 1 are the values, with a submit to go to page 2 (a sort of confirmation screen). On page 2, I have a submit and a back button.

According to Example #8 in the Examples module, we use a submit button for the back button, with a custom #submit handler, as so:

```
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Submit'),
  '#submit' => array('my_final_submit_function'),
);

$form['back'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('<< Back'),
  '#submit' => array('my_back_button_handler_function'),
);
```

Everything works fine until I try to submit or hit back. Whichever button (submit or back) is placed first in the code is the button Drupal 7 registers as the clicked button, including in the form_state. Each function has their own #submit pointing to a different function. I have confirmed that Drupal can see/execute both functions.

Whichever submit button Drupal thinks was triggered is the #submit handler that gets processed.

When I put the back button first, both buttons trigger the back button functionality. When I put the submit button first, both trigger the submit logic. Although the examples module does not set a #name on each (to prevent name=op for both fields), I've tried doing that. I've tried it without that. It doesn't seem to make a difference.

I am not using an image_button, but a normal '#type'='submit'. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: I know it's an old question but still wonder if you have figured anything out. I ran into same issue and all of the solutions I can find online didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out the trigger button like this

$form_state['triggering_element']['#value'] == 'Back'

That way you will sure what to do with the operation performed.

Comment: Thanks Vishal. Unfortunately, this is exactly where Drupal is failing.  Drupal is defaulting to the first button's details no matter which button is clicked. This includes the #name, #value, #submit, et al. In fact, visually, when I click one button, I see the other button fire as if both buttons are linked. It's all very strange.